# Why do we use 3 channel R,G,B to represent color?

Tags: experimental-psychology

I read that there're some more colors which cannot be represented by R,G,B. What is the experiment that lead people to use 3 variables R,G,B?

Can that experiment be replicated in other modals, such as what is the dimension of auditory perception, or tactile perception?

Comment: This is actually a physics question I believe. All the visible colors of light can be represented by combinations of red, green, and blue. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_primaries#Additive_primaries

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong! See my answer below.

Comment: there are other color representation spaces too,  e.g., L*a*b http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space

Comment: Thanks! I know that, but why is dimension 3? Why not 2 dimension, or 10 dimension??

Comment: Because we have three types of cone cells in our eyes, is my understanding from what I've read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After researching this a bit more, I believe this is actually a *biology* question, not a physics one.

The specific term I believe you're searching for is **Trichromacy**, which [Wikipedia defines as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichromacy):

> Trichromacy or trichromaticism is the condition of possessing three independent channels for conveying color information, derived from the three different cone types.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGK5F.png) Organisms with trichromacy are called trichromats.

Reading the Wikipedia article, it appears that the [cone cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell)  Humans (and other trichromats) come in three different variations; the different variations are sensitive to red, green, and blue light, as depicted in this image [(again from Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cones_SMJ2_E.svg)<sup>1</sup>:

> [image: Normalized responsivity spectra of human cone cells, S, M, and L types]
>
> Normalized responsivity spectra of human cone cells, S, M, and L types

We've evolved these three cone types because red, green and blue are [additive primaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_primaries#Additive_primaries), meaning most of the whole range of visible light can be represented by combinations of these colors. Quoting Wikipedia again:

> Even the four-primary technology does not yet reach the range of colors the human eye is theoretically capable of perceiving (as defined by the sample-based estimate called the Pointer Gamut[17]), with 4-primary LED prototypes providing typically about 87% and 5-primary prototypes about 95%. Several firms, including Samsung and Mitsubishi, have demonstrated LED displays with five or six "primaries", or color LED point light sources per pixel.[18] A recent academic literature review claims a gamut of 99% can be achieved with 5-primary LED technology.

I'm not sure what the experiment you're referring to was, but I doubt it would translate nearly as nicely into sound, as RGB is based on the biology of the eye specifically.

<sub>1: Attribution: [Vanessaezekowitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Vanessaezekowitz) at en.wikipedia</sub>